# Mvc4 set user as logged in when user info is found in the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a new mvc4 site,and am using mvc4 forms authentication.

the users of the site expect to be able to login to the companies main site and click on a link and go to this new site i am developing. the old site stores the logged in user in a session variable. is it possible for me to check if the session variable exists and log the user in to my forms authentication? or will they need to login again?

Comment: If you develop the new site, how do you want to get session of the old site?

Comment: The login again is the easiest thing to develop. If want login integration (pretty much single sign on) that's a bit (more) harder

Comment: @Alexander both sites are on the same IIS, so I should be able to obtain the session variable between both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the same machineKey section in your web.config in system.web like this:

```
<system.web>
<machineKey validationKey="SAME_KEY_GOES_HERE" ... />
...
```

You can [generate machineKey here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).

Then your goal is to pass all the authentication cookies from one website to another. I think you can store them in database, and provide authenticated users with an unique link to your new website. New website can read the key from database, and set cookie values obtained from the existing website. After that, user will be authenticated on your new website.

Update:

There could be easier and little bit less secure way of doing this. Don't keep cookie data in database, just create a form on the first website with post action. This form must contain all authentication cookies in hidden values. *Action* of the form must point to your second website. On the second website, you just need to place submitted form values to cookies. That's it! Much easier! (yep, and you need same machine key)